# Java Regex does not match

Tags: java, regex

I know that this kind of questions are proposed very often, but
I can't figure out why this RegEx does not match.
I want to check if there is a "M" at the beginning of the line, or not.
Finaly, i want the path at the end of the line.
This is why startsWith() doesn't fit my Needs.

```
line = "M            72208    70779 koj          src\com\company\testproject\TestDomainf1.java";

if (line.matches("^(M?)(.*)$")) {}
```

I've also tried the other way out:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(M?)");
Matcher m = datePatt.matcher(line);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("yay!");
}

if (line.matches("(M?)(.*)")) {}
```

Thanks

Comment: And what specific misbehavior are you getting? (Also, is your actual scenario more complicated than what you posted? If not, why aren't you just using `line.charAt(0)`?)

Comment: `M?` means "0 or 1 `M` characters", which will always be true.

Comment: what i want is the path at the end of the line.
That's why i worked with ()

Comment: In this case you need to first find where the path begins. Basically, it's a new question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need a regex for that. Just use [`String#startsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if (line.startsWith("M")) {
    // code here
}
```

OR else use [`String#toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

```
if (line.length() > 0 && line.toCharArray()[0] == 'M') {
    // code here
}
```

**EDIT:** After your edited requirement to get path from input string.

You still can avoid regex and have your code like this:

```
String path="";
if (line.startsWith("M"))
    path = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
System.out.println(path);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
src\com\company\testproject\TestDomainf1.java
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct regex would be simply

```
line.matches("M.*")
```

since the `matches` method enforces that the whole input sequence must match. However, this is such a simple problem that I wonder if you really need a regex for it. A plain

```
line.startsWith("M")
```

or

```
line.length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) == 'M'
```

or even just

```
line.indexOf('M') == 0
```

will work for your requirement.

#### Performance?

If you are also interested in performance, my second and third options win in that department, whereas the first one may easily be the slowest option: it must first *compile* the regex, then evaluate it. `indexOf` has the problem that its worst case is scanning the whole string.

## UPDATE

In the meantime you have completely restated your question and made it clear that the regex is what you really need. In this case the following should work:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("M.*?(\\S+)").matcher(input);
System.out.println(m.matches()? m.group(1) : "no match");
```

Note, this only works if the path doesn't contain spaces. If it does, then the problem is much harder.

Comment: *Performance?* : Even if you use `static Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);` for heavy match processes?

Comment: Finally, i want the path at the end of the line. 
This is why i used ()  Groups and startsWith() doesn't fit my Needs.

Comment: Did you test the code? If i run it with the input i've posted above, i get no matches at all.
It matches when i replace the S with s, but then the Group doesn't contain the path

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern to check whether an `M` character appears as at the beginning of the string:

```
if (line.matches("M.*"))
```

But for something this simple, you can just use this:

```
if (line.length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) == 'M')
```

Comment: The regex is wrong: it will match only the literal line "M". Also, no need for begin/end anchors; that's implied by the semantics of `matches`.

Comment: `line.matches("^M")` will fail if line has any character after M.

Comment: And `charAt(0)` will throw an unwanted exception for empty string.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks, I haven't written any Java in quite a while, so I'm a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this

```
line.startsWith("M");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String str = new String("M 72208 70779 kij src/com/knapp/testproject/TestDomainf1.java");

   if(str.startsWith("M") ){
        ------------------------
        ------------------------
   }
```

Comment: Finally, i want the path at the end of the line. This is why startsWith() doesn't fit my Needs.

Comment: @der_juergen Add an **EDIT** to your post and complete it with the new answer (do not delete first lines, new readers will understand the thread)

Answer (score 0):

If you need Path, you can split (I guess than `\t` is the separator) the string and take the latest field:

```
String[] tabS = "M            72208    70779 kij          src\com\knapp\testproject\TestDomainf1.java".split("\t");
String path = tabS[tabS.length-1];
```