# Java Regex does not match - groups

Tags: java, regex

I know that this kind of questions are proposed very often, but
I can't figure out why this RegEx does not match.
I want to check if there is a "M" at the beginning of the line, or not.
**Finally**, i want the path at the end of the line.
This is why startsWith() doesn't fit my Needs.

```
line = "M      72208  70779 aab   src\com\aut\testproject\TestDomainf1.java";

if (line.matches("^(M?)(.*)$")) {}
```

I've also tried the other way out:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(M?)");
Matcher m = datePatt.matcher(line);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("yay!");
}

if (line.matches("(M?)(.*)")) {}
```

Thanks

Comment: In your specific case, wouldn't `line.startsWith("M")` do the trick?

Comment: Three consecutive voted-down questions, that doesn't happen pretty often.

Comment: I've allready posted this question, but without the important fact that i Need the path at the end of the line.
So, if there is an M at the beginning, I want the path at the end of the line.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314450/java-regex-does-not-match?rq=1

Comment: @BackSlash This is even given as answer in the duplicate question

Comment: @der_juergen When Marko Topolnik (in a comment on your previous/original question) said it was a new question, he didn't mean post a duplicate question. You need to reword this question to indicate what specifically you need help with in order to post it as a separate question. If it turns out that rewording the question does not make it very different from your original question, then you should go back and change the original question and get rid of this one. Basically, don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: Just saw that this question is a repost of a previous one, reposting will not help you getting more answer, this will just attract downvotes and your question will likely be closed.

Comment: der_juergen: don't ask a new question to add something, just edit your previous one.

Comment: okay. sorry for that.
Nevertheless, you are awesome. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be simple:

```
    if (line.startsWith("M")) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String path = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
    }
```